# How to aggregate upvote and post tables together in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking for a way to aggregate posts and the upvotes related to that post together using PostgreSQL. I want to make it similar to reddit's upvote systems, where upvotes come already fetched and don't need to be loaded on client side.

I have made these simple tables.

**`upvotes.sql`**

```sql
CREATE TABLE upvotes (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    post_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES posts(id)
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

**`users.sql`**

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
```

**`posts.sql`**

```sql
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    content VARCHAR NOT NULL
)
```

Basically I want to make my response look something like this:

**`post.json`**

```json
{
    id: 1234,
    content: "foo",
    upvotes: 1234
}
```

Is there a way for doing this with a single query? I feel like this is a simple question but don't really know how to make it work...

Comment: you can use a subquery for the upvote counts;

`SELECT *, ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM "upvotes" WHERE "post_id" = p."id" ) AS "upvotes" FROM "posts" AS p`

you'll also need indexes on the upvotes table

Comment: Thank you, this worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is.

```sql
select to_jsonb(t.*)
from
(
  select p.id, p.content, count(*) upvotes_count
  from posts p 
  inner join upvotes uv on p.id = uv.post_id 
  group by p.id, p.contents
) t
-- where id = 1234;
```

Please note that if `posts.id` is primary key then `p.contents` is redundant in the `group by` clause. We do not actually pay attention who are the users that upvoted the post but only how many they are. So table `users` is not used in the query.

Comment: Thank you. This worked